# CSS hoverable dropdown menu doesn't close on mobile

Tags: css, responsive

I have implemented a hoverable dropdown menu just as this example from w3schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

On my PC it works perfectly, but I tried the page on an iPhone with iOS 12.1.2 and the menu is shown, but it doesn't go away when I touch something outside of the menu even if it's the button that opened the menu. It was tested on Safari Mobile and Chrome for iOS.

I attempted this implementation, but nothing changed:

[Mobile dropdown menu won't go away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307972/mobile-dropdown-menu-wont-go-away)

My structure is something like this:

```
<div class="mobile__nav-wrapper>
  <button type="button" class="mobile__nav-button"></button>
  <div class="mobile__nav-content">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="page">Page</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I've tried that implementation like this (index.gif=tested.gif):

```
<div class="mobile__nav-wrapper>
  <button type="button" class="mobile__nav-button"></button>
  <div class="mobile__nav-content">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="page">Page</a>
  </div>
  <img class="close" src="img/index.gif" />
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.mobile__nav-wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top:1.6em;
    right: 0.2em;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mobile__nav__btn-animation{
    0%   {background-color: rgba(244,244,244,0.95);-webkit-box-shadow: none;box-shadow: none; color: #C0B283;}
    25%  {background-color: rgba(190,170,130,0.95);-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #F4F4F4;box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #F4F4F4; color: #F4F4F4;}
    50%  {background-color: rgba(244,244,244,0.95);-webkit-box-shadow: none;box-shadow: none; color: #C0B283;}
    75%  {background-color: rgba(190,170,130,0.95);-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #F4F4F4;box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #F4F4F4; color: #F4F4F4;}
    100% {background-color: rgba(244,244,244,0.95);-webkit-box-shadow: none;box-shadow: none; color: #C0B283;}
}
@keyframes mobile__nav__btn-animation{
    0%   {background-color: rgba(244,244,244,0.95);-webkit-box-shadow: none;box-shadow: none; color: #C0B283;}
    25%  {background-color: rgba(190,170,130,0.95);-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #F4F4F4;box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #F4F4F4; color: #F4F4F4;}
    50%  {background-color: rgba(244,244,244,0.95);-webkit-box-shadow: none;box-shadow: none; color: #C0B283;}
    75%  {background-color: rgba(190,170,130,0.95);-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #F4F4F4;box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #F4F4F4; color: #F4F4F4;}
    100% {background-color: rgba(244,244,244,0.95);-webkit-box-shadow: none;box-shadow: none; color: #C0B283;}
}
.mobile__nav-btn{
    font-size: 1rem;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #575757;
    padding: 0.50em 0.70em;
    background-color: rgba(244,244,244,0.95);
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;

    -webkit-animation-name: mobile__nav__btn-animation;

            animation-name: mobile__nav__btn-animation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
            animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.mobile__nav-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.mobile__nav-content a{
    color: #575757;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -100vw;
}
.mobile__nav-content a:hover{
    background-color: rgba(163,183,108,0.85);
}
/*--------for the safari mobile browser----------*/
div img.close {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

div .mobile__nav-wraper:hover + img {
  display: block;
}
/*-------end of the safari mobile browser----------*/
.mobile__nav-wrapper:hover .mobile__nav-content{
    display: block;
}
```

How can I achieve this without using JS? Or it's strictly necessary?

-----UPDATE----
As it was asked by Viira, here is a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9ymj80hw/1/

Comment: a jsfiddle or codepen would be helpful!

Comment: You can read this article to learn more about `hover`, `focus` on dropdown menus (not a answer to your question) :
[Dropdown Menus with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/)

Comment: Viira Done, you can check it now

Comment: ParthoDas Thanks, i'm going to check that, maybe I'll find something useful there

Answer (score 2):

I was just searching for a solution to this, also. I eventually solved it by adding a `tabindex` to the `<body>` tag, like this:

```
<body tabindex="0">
```

This little trick allowed iPad Safari to focus on the body when it's tapped on, and remove the focus from the dropdown menu.